# Properties of prime characteristic, $p > 0$

Tags: group-theory

Let $R$ be a ring of prime characteristic, $p > 0$ and $x,y \in R$. Show that:

$$(x+y)^p = x^p + y^p$$

---

To recall definition; a characteristic of $R$ is $n\in\mathbb N \cup \{0\}$, such that $\forall a \in R, na = 0.$ If such a number does not exist then $n=0$.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

First, make sure you understand why the statement of this theorem holds over any commutative ring with unity, then apply it to the expression $(x + y)^p$.  Since you are in characteristic $p$, any element of the form $nx$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, with $p | n$ will be equal to $0$ (make sure you can explain this step too!).  Finally, you need to use the fact that $p | \binom{p}{i}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq p - 1$.  This is not too difficult to prove, as long as you're satisfied using combinatorial arguments to conclude that $\binom{a}{b} \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$, $b \leq a$.  If you're ok with all of that, then just think about the prime factorizations of the numerator and denominator in $\binom{p}{i}$.

Hope this helps!